# How to get ARN for SNS Topic created using cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have created SNS using cloud formation like this -

```
  MYSNS:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: "MYSNS"
      TopicName: "MYSNS"
```

Now, I want to publish message to this topic using Java but

`snsClient.publish(snsARN, snsEvent);`

sns client requires ARN to publish the event. How I can get SNS Topic ARN?

Edit 1: Post deployment we can get the ARN, but don't want this way.

Ex - We can get SQS url by it's Name using SQS Client like this - 
`sqsClient.getQueueUrl(dlqName).getQueueUrl();` I am looking for similar way in case of SNS.

Comment: you can try AWS::SNS::Subscription, for AWS::SNS::Topic. [AWS::SNS::Subscription,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the ARN yourself:

```
arn:aws:sns:<region>:<account>:MYSNS
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this in cloudformation template to get the created SNS's ARN

`!Ref MYSNS`